# Indoor plant leaves blackening- help! It may take over second plant

Tags: identification, diagnosis, indoors, leaves

[image]

One leaf is almost completely curled and black and the others have started progressing with the same thing. It’s been sitting with direct sunlight by the window during our winter in Maryland. Is it the cold? Watering, direct sunlight? Not sure if this is even a white birds of paradise, it was gifted to us. Help please!

Comment: I can't tell what size pot your plant is in, and actually, can't  really see the whole plant either. Does the pot have drainage holes? How much water do you give and do you empty out any excess water from any outer pot or tray afterwards? Is the plant standing near a heat source, like a radiator? Are your windows double or single glazed?  Does it get cold draughts?

Comment: The put is huge, it might actually be too big for the plant. It has drainage holes at the bottom and a catch plate. I water it about twice a week, sometimes I forget and only water it once but during the cold months it doesn’t need too much. It was basically touching the window, it is double glazed. It is direct exposure to sun.

Comment: When you touch the window with your hand is it cold?   Tropical plants can't handle cold foliage.  Most tropical plants will tolerate temp. down to 50°f (10°c), but not all.  What has the weather been like their lately.  I know in VA the fall can be anywhere from high 70s to low 30s and it could be one of the temps all day or fluctuate between the two in one day.   How cold has that window been getting?     Did you recently move the plant to this location or has it been there for months.  Is this a south or west facing window?  What time of day is this direct sun?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there may be 2 factors here.Watering twice a week wouldn't be healthy for any plant in my opinion.Check the root ball, make sure it's not soggy. Secondly,if you have plants that are getting sun directly through a window, double pane or single, the heat is intense. After all, the sun is closer to the earth during the winter. I would watch my watering, the roots need oxygen too, and move it away from the direct sunlight, give it in-direct sun. If all is lost, cut the healthy cane or stem, root it and start another. Good Luck